# Retrieving and display a sum of values with AJAX and CodeIgniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I don't know if I am using the correct syntax but I would like to retrieve a sum of values and display it in a view.

**Controller code:**

```
public function stockArticle()
{
    $donnees_post = $this->input->post();

    $this->load->model('batchquantity_model');

    $stock = $this->batchquantity_model->getStockArticle($donnees_post);

    echo json_encode($stock);
}
```

**Model code:**

```
public function getStockArticle($donnees_post)
{
    $reponse = [];

    if(isset($donnees_post['idArticle']) && isset($donnees_post['idStorage']))
    {  
        $this->db->select_sum('quantite');
        $this->db->from('batchquantity');
        $this->db->join('lots', 'batchquantity.idLot = lots.id');
        $this->db->where('idArticle', $donnees_post['idArticle']);
        $this->db->where('idStorage', $donnees_post['idStorage']);

        $reponse = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    return $reponse;   
}
```

**AJAX fetch code in the view:**

```
$('#articles').change(function(){
     
        var idArticle = $(this).val();
        var idStorage = $('#storages').val();
     
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/batchquantity/stockArticle',
            method: 'post',
            data: {idArticle: idArticle, idStorage: idStorage},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){

                var len = response.length;

                if(len > 0){

                   stock = response[0].quantite;

                }
                else
                {
                    stock = 0;
                }

                $('#stock').val(stock);  

            }
        });
    });
```

Would there be an error in my code since each time I have a null value which appears when I launch a `alert(response [0].quantite);` in my jQuery script

Comment: what you get in `alert(response);`??

Comment: please show us what expected output you want in picture please??

Comment: after running your code what response did you get?

Comment: Kumar, I have already modified my code, especially my model as recommended to me by Suii. But now I only have 0 as an answer even though the item has a quantity greater than 0. What I want to do is simple: display the quantity of an item when it is selected in a select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just row in your model like this

`$this->db->get()->row();`

so that it will return single result and you can just display it right away on your javascript like this.

```
$('#articles').change(function(){
 
    var idArticle = $(this).val();
    var idStorage = $('#storages').val();
 
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?=base_url()?>index.php/batchquantity/stockArticle',
        method: 'post',
        data: {idArticle: idArticle, idStorage: idStorage},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.length){
               stock = response.quantite;
            }
            else
            {
                stock = 0;
            }

            $('#stock').val(stock);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified my code as you asked me but now instead of null, I now systematically have the value 0 even though the article exists in the database and has a quantity greater than 0

Comment: Can  you print_r($reponse); the response on your model maybe there is no data result using your query.

Comment: Hi suii you were right there was a problem but in the code of my view. I corrected it and everything is back to normal. Thank you again for your contribution which saves me.